# Launch Sharepoint Hosted App from a link in a webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

You know, If it is possible to launch a SharePoint app from a webpart in the home page?

I like to insert an image in a webpart and then when the user click on image or link the SharePoint app is launched.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the link to the App on the Quick Launch or the icon for it on the Site Contents page, you can copy the link to the App to your clipboard.  This will copy the redirect link for it and then you can use that when linking your image from a content page...

Comment: Thanks John, but that i like is a get one button in the page that lauch the app whe the user click on the button. It is posible? Maybe with a webpart?

Comment: You can just use an image (maybe an image of a button) that is linked to your app in a Content Editor web part...